# Windows 7 Laptop Sound: Mixer has green bar but no sound from speakers of headphone jack

Tags: windows-7, audio

Have a Sony Vaio laptop. Sound bar on sound mixer is green but no sound from speakers or headphones.
Wondering what should I check?

Answer (score 0):

Check the physical connection to ensure your headphones are fully in. Take them out and put them in again.

Check that nothing is muting your headphones from the headphones own hardware.

Check that your headphones work with another device.

Reinstall your sound driver.

Also check if your computer has multiple audio outputs. Ensure headphones are selected for your output.
[image]

Goto Control panels -> sound to find this.

Comment: Just noticed that Speakers/Headphones is not listed under Playback, just Digital Audio

Comment: Perhaps try reinstalling the sound driver then so you can rule it out at least.